# magento 2 category url_rewrites issue

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I am using Magento 2.3

when I create new category and check url_rewrite and front end that url generate like this **domain.com/parent.html/subcategory.html**

instead I need url like **domain.com/parent/subcategory.html**

yes I can edit in `url_rewrite` by manually. I want to solve it permanent

It is strange while in local setup `Magento2.3` its working fine.

any idea. why this happen?

Please check my `store->config->catalog->SEO` setings below
[image]